# Overloaded Equals method and putVal method in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I have two methods in my Emp class

```
class Emp
{
  String empId;
  public boolean equals(Emp e){..}
  public boolean equals(Object o){..}
  public int hashCode(){
  return empId.hashCode();
 }
}
```

Now if a am trying to add Emp objects to a `HashSet<Emp>`.

If i look at the code of HashMap's putVal method which is used to compare and put values to the set. The code never casts your passed object to `java.lang.Object`.So every time the `equals(Emp)` version should get called.

But every time `equals(Object o)` gets called.I want to know when is this Emp converted to java.lang.Object so that everyTime the `equals(Object o)` gets called.

Below is the putval snippet i am using:

```
 final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
                        boolean evict) {
   Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
   if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
     n = (tab = resize()).length;
   if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
     tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
   else {
     Node<K,V> e; K k;
     if (p.hash == hash &&
          ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
       e = p;
     else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
       e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
                     ....
    }
```

Comment: The other thing to recommend here: better always use braces for then/else statements; even when it is a just a single statement. And: be precise about formatting/indenting; as that really helps with reading / understanding code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler erases the generic type parameters, so `K` and `V` become `Object` when the code is compiled. Therefore `key.equals(k)` executes `equals(Object o)`.

Comment: Thanks again Eran. :)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the correct argument from Eran; the point is **don't do** that.

Do not **overload** `public boolean equals(Object)`!

This is a method with a very defined and clear and known contract in Java. Adding your own public `equals(Emp)` **only** increases your risks of creating bugs.

If at all, make that method private; and call it from within the `equals(Object)` method.

You see, *overloading* is a concept that should be used really carefully, as all of that happens at **compile** time; and especially when combining it with polymorphism, unexpected things can happen at runtime (as you just learned).

Comment: Thanks GhostCat .Points noted.